# Delphi - pass TValue to generic method

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-10.1-berlin

I need to iterate through a class which has a complex structure using RTTI. The class has several record members which I also want to iterate.

```
 TRTTIHelpers<T> = class
  public
    class function DoGetValuesForClass(aClassInst: T): TStringList;
    class function DoGetValuesForRecord(aRec: T): TStringList;
  end;
```

I know when I have a member in the class which is a record:

```
   for prop in rt.GetProperties() do
    begin
      if prop.PropertyType is TRttiRecordType then
      begin
        lValue := prop.GetValue(aInst);
        Result.AddStrings(TRTTIHelpers<T>.DoGetValuesForRecord(TValue)); <--
      end
```

How can I pass the [TValue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Rtti.TValue) as a parameter to DoGetValuesForRecord so I can also iterate through the record?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`AsType<T>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TValue.AsType) method of `TValue` to cast the value to `T`:

```
lValue := prop.GetValue(aInst);
Result.AddStrings(TRTTIHelpers<T>.DoGetValuesForRecord(lValue.AsType<T>));
```

This simple program demonstrates this:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.RTTI;

type
  TMyRecord = record
    foo: Integer;
  end;

  TMyClass = class
    function GetRec: TMyRecord;
    property Rec: TMyRecord read GetRec;
    function GetInt: Integer;
    property Int: Integer read GetInt;
  end;

function TMyClass.GetRec: TMyRecord;
begin
  Result.foo := 42;
end;

function TMyClass.GetInt: Integer;
begin
  Result := 666;
end;

procedure Main;
var
  inst: TMyClass;
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  typ: TRttiType;
  prop: TRttiProperty;
  value: TValue;
  rec: TMyRecord;
begin
  inst := TMyClass.Create;
  typ := ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(TMyClass));
  for prop in typ.GetProperties do begin
    if prop.Name='Rec' then begin
      value := prop.GetValue(inst);
      rec := value.AsType<TMyRecord>;
      Writeln(rec.foo);
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Of course, this does require that the property `prop` is of the correct type. If not then you will encounter a run time error. In my example above, I ensure that is so by testing the name of the property to make sure I get the desired property. If you remove that test then the program fails with a run time `EInvalidCast` error.

Looking at your code I suspect that you are quite likely to encounter such errors. It would be surprising to me if every single property of `rt` was of the same type.

Looking at `TRTTIHelpers<T>` I don't think it will be very useful to you in its current form. At least, you it won't interact well with code based on RTTI. The reason being that calls to `TRTTIHelpers<T>` require you to supply the type parameter at compile time. But with RTTI code, you don't know that type at compile time. I suspect that `TRTTIHelpers<T>` should probably not be a generic class, and instead use RTTI types to offer you functionality that is flexible for run time determined typing. This advice could of course be wrong, but I only have the small excerpts of code in the question to guide me.

Comment: Well, this is the answer to the question you asked. The run time error is telling you that whatever is in `lValue` it is not of type `T`.

Comment: What is in lValue is of type TRTTIRecordType -  if prop.PropertyType is TRttiRecordType then - and I have in my class a record type

Comment: Yes, a record type. But not necessarily the same type as the generic `T`, as the run time error informs you.

Comment: I basically have the same code as you've posted, except the fact that I want to pass the value from the line value := prop.GetValue(inst); as a generic type to another function. Is this possible?

Comment: The code in my answer proves that it is correct. Your error is surely one of fundamental understanding, and you aren't going to make progress without gaining that understanding. Don't imagine that some magic block of code will unstick you. You think that `lValue` contains a record of type `T`, but the system tells you that it does not. Trust the system. You asked how to extract the value from `TValue` as a specific type, and my answer clearly demonstrates that. Now it is up to you to debug your program.